# Moments of solution of simple SDE

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $b\in \mathbb{R},\, \sigma>0,  \,  x \in \mathbb{R}$ be constants and $X$ the solution of the SDE
$$
dX_t= b X_t dt + \sigma X_t dW_t , \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \;  X_0 = x
$$
Find $\mathbb{E} X_t^k$ for all natural numbers $k$ and $t \geq 0 $ fixed.

I have tried using Itò for $X^k$ but then realized I cannot even solve the questions for $k=1$

Comment: Most likely you want $\sigma X_t\,dW_t$. Then the solution is explicit. It's called geometric Brownian motion. To find it by hand write $Y_t=\log(X_t)$ and use Ito.

Comment: Thank you I have edited the question; yes that should solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness, applying Itô's lemma to $Y_t = log(X_t)$ as julien mentioned, or postulating a solution of the form $X_t = X_0 \exp(at + bW_t)$, one obtains:
\begin{equation}
X_t = X_0 \exp\left( \left( r-\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \right) t + \sigma W_t\right).
\end{equation}
Then, taking expectations, 
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[X_{t}^{k}] = X_0 \exp\left( \left( r-\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \right) kt \right) \mathbb{E}\left[ e^{k \sigma W_t} \right] = \exp\left( \left( r-\frac{1}{2} k\sigma^2  +  \frac{1}{2} k^2 \sigma^2 \right) t \right),
\end{equation}
by the moment generating function of $k \sigma W_t \sim N(0,k^2 \sigma^2t) $.